# jQuery selector objects - need to use only certain one

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this:

```
console.log($("div[id^='highc']"));
```

This prints me an array of objects. I can easily get what I want by typing:

```
console.log($("div[id^='highc']")[0]);
```

Now, `$("div[id^='highc']").append('text')` appends to all of the objects in a returned array. How can I assign to a certain object IN the array?

This didn't work:

`$("div[id^='highc'][0]").append('text')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that `$("div[id^='highc']")` returns [a jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) that contains a collection of [DOM elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) (if anything is selected). Since jQuery objects are *similar* to arrays, `$("div[id^='highc']")[0]` will return the first DOM element in the jQuery object.

The issue that you're *likely* experiencing is that you can't use jQuery methods (like `.append()`) on native DOM elements. In other words, if you are chaining the `.append()` method on the first [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) in the jQuery object (i.e., `$("div[id^='highc']")[0].append(...)`), you will receive an error stating that `.append()` is not a function:

> Uncaught TypeError: `$(...)[0].append` is not a function

Since the `.append()` methods operates on a jQuery object, you could use the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) in order to retrieve a jQuery object containing the element based on its index.

```
$("div[id^='highc']").eq(0).append('Text');
```

Alternatively, an uglier approach would be to wrap the DOM element with `$()` in order to return a jQuery object:

```
$($("div[id^='highc']")[0]).append('Text');
```

---

Side note:

In your question you used both `$("div[id^='highc'][0]")` and `$("div[id^='highc']")[0]`. I'm assuming it was a typo and you meant the latter since `$("div[id^='highc'][0]")` wouldn't return any elements due to the fact that the elements probably don't have a `[0]` attribute. You probably attempted to use the `.append()` method with `[0]` outside of the selector.

Comment: .eq() rocked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when you tried `$("div[id^='highc'][0]").append('text')`, you put the `[0]` **inside the selector** rather than outside it. The correct code is `$("div[id^='highc']")[0].append('text')`